# UNIX column command: wrong column width for headers

Tags: shell, unix, formatting

So I have this as my data file

```
Account Number ena5LHtEj Name ena5LHtEj Account Type ena5LHtEj Balance
1 ena5LHtEj foo ena5LHtEj 1 ena5LHtEj 100
1 ena5LHtEj foo ena5LHtEj 1 ena5LHtEj 100
1 ena5LHtEj foo ena5LHtEj 1 ena5LHtEj 100
```

Line 1 is the column names. The `ena5LHtEj` is a randomly generated delimiter. And other 3 lines are rows. Here is the command I am running

```
column -t -s "$delimiter" data
```

The delimiter variable has the value `ena5LHtEj` and here is the output it gives

```
Accou   Numb  r     N    m      Accou   Typ      B  l  c
1       foo    1    100
1       foo    1    100
1       foo    1    100
1       foo    1    100
```

So the rows get parsed correctly, but the column headings don't get parsed. This is not because of spaces in header names because I tried removing the space. Only difference between first and second line is the width. I am running this on ubuntu terminal with bash.

Here is what it should give / I want

```
Account Number Name   Account Type Balance
1              foo    1            100
1              foo    1            100
1              foo    1            100
1              foo    1            100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trouble comes from the misunderstanding that the delimiter is not a string but a set of characters; each of those (not "all in the given order") is a possible delimiter.  Hence things like "Number" get split at the "e" because "e" is part of "ena5LHtEj".

Try this:

```
column -t -s "|" <(sed 's/ena5LHtEj/|/g' < data)
```

to convert the string-delimiter you've got into a one-character delimiter (`|` in this case).  The result is what you specified in your question.

Comment: ah right, I can change the delimiter any time so I will change the delimiter itself to the pipe. Thanks!